# TAB Layout Width

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs, tabwidget

I am stuck in my xml code

```
<TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I am trying to change the width to a custom set dip number but

```
android:layout_width="50dip"
```

is not making any affect to the tab width layout
any suggenstion on this one please ?

Here is the full XML file Layout on pasteBin

http://pastebin.com/7vi4Pi8Z

Thanks 
Shiraz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No body contributed the answer but after few hours of struggle i have found the way to 
set the width of tabs in java code...
here you go, if some one may need this later

```
TabWidget tabWidget = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
final int tabChildrenCount = tabWidget.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i< tabChildrenCount; i++)
{
        // change the value 110 to whatever suits you for tab width
    tHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width = 110;
}
```

many thanks 
shiraz

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need each tab different size, then simplest width reduction may be adding something like

```
android:weightSum="5"
```

to your TabWidget parameters.